# how to read the response which is a sound file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, server, client-server

I am sending a request to the server and server is sending a response back. But the response is in the form of sound file.
working - I am sending the request, response is received on the terminal, so I am writing it to text but later how to convert that into a sound file (.wav). The response from the server is as shown below.

The response as a text in the beginning and the binary in the middle and later text in the end. how to get a sound file out of it ? someone help me in this ?

Comment: Please add the minimum server + client code which allows us to execute your process so we can better help you

Comment: Do you have control over the server code as well ?  or is it considered a black box ?

Comment: I dont have control over the server. I have the message format, I am using it to send a request and I will receive the response from the server as in my question.