# How to remove the first four lines and the last 12 lines in to a file in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, mime

```
        h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
        h.set_debuglevel(0)

        headers = {

        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%s" % (boundary,),

        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",

        }

        h.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
        res = h.getresponse()
        #print res.read()
        data = """MIME-Version: 1.0
        Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
        """ + res.read()

        msg = email.message_from_string(data)
        #print msg

        for index, part in enumerate(msg.walk(), start=1):
            content_type = part.get_content_type()
            #print content_type
            payload = part.get_payload()
            print res.getheaders()

            if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
                with open('output.pcm'.format(index), 'wb') as f_pcm:
                    print f_pcm.write(payload)
```

I am sending a request to the server and the server is sending a response back to the client as above in the form of `.txt`. The `.txt` contains an information header on the top and header at the bottom, which is of text format and the rest is binary.

How to write and parse the text and write it into a separate `.txt` file,  and the binary into `.pcm` file?

Comment: Please could you edit the question to include the code you are using to get this.

Comment: I added my code but not complete code.

Comment: Use python's [`email`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email) package for parsing MIME.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that ? I am trying and not getting.

Comment: See also the following [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154683/how-to-read-the-response-which-is-a-sound-file-in-python)  from the OP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064184/remove-lines-from-textfile-with-python

Comment: i tried that but can you please tell me how to do it for my example ?

Comment: Show us what you tried.  Post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your code example does not work.  `uri`, `h`, `boundary` and `body` are not defined.

Comment: @sam Can you please attach your file `Output.txt` eg. with Skydrive or Dropbox, so that we have a example to work with. Using your posted file content does not work for me.

Comment: I attached everything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following kind of approach is recommended using Python's [`email`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html?highlight=email#module-email) library to try and decode the MIME:

```
import ssl
import os
import json
import email
import uuid
from io import BytesIO
import httplib


input_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
output_folder = os.path.join(input_folder, 'output')

def get_filename(ext, base, sub_folder):
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(base, ext)
    return os.path.join(output_folder, sub_folder, filename)

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
        if f_file1.read() == f_file2.read():
            print 'Same:\n  {}\n  {}'.format(file1, file2)
        else:
            print 'Different:\n  {}\n  {}'.format(file1, file2)

class Part(object):
    """Represent a part in a multipart messsage"""

    def __init__(self, name, contentType, data, paramName=None):
        super(Part, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.paramName = paramName
        self.contentType = contentType
        self.data = data

    def encode(self):
        body = BytesIO()

        if self.paramName:
            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; paramName="%s"\r\n' % (self.name, self.paramName))
        else:
            body.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"\r\n' % (self.name,))

        body.write("Content-Type: %s\r\n" % (self.contentType,))
        body.write("\r\n")
        body.write(self.data)
        return body.getvalue()

class Request(object):
    """A handy class for creating a request"""

    def __init__(self):    
        super(Request, self).__init__()
        self.parameters = []

    def add_json_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):
        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="application/json; charset=utf-8", data=data))

    def add_audio_parameter(self, name, paramName, data):
        self.parameters.append(Part(name=name, paramName=paramName, contentType="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000", data=data))

    def encode(self):
        boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex
        body = BytesIO()

        for parameter in self.parameters:
            body.write("--%s\r\n" % (boundary,))
            body.write(parameter.encode())
            body.write("\r\n")

        body.write("--%s--\r\n" % (boundary,))
        return body.getvalue(), boundary


def get_tts(required_text, LNG):
    required_text = required_text.strip()
    output_filename = "".join([x if x.isalnum() else "_" for x in required_text[:80]]) 

    host = "mtldev08.nuance.com"
    port = 443
    uri = "/NmspServlet/"

    if LNG == "ENG":
        parameters = {'lang' : 'eng_GBR', 'location' : '47.4925, 19.0513'}

    if LNG == "GED":
        parameters = {'lang' : 'deu-DEU', 'location' : '48.396231, 9.972909'}

    RequestData = """{
        "appKey": "9c9fa7201e90d3d96718bc3f36ce4cfe1781f2e82f4e5792996623b3b474fee2c77699eb5354f2136063e1ff19c378f0f6dd984471a38ca5c393801bffb062d6",
        "appId": "NMDPTRIAL_AutomotiveTesting_NCS61HTTP",
        "uId": "Alexander",
        "inCodec": "PCM_16_8K",
        "outCodec": "PCM_16_8K",
        "cmdName": "NVC_TTS_CMD",
        "appName": "Python",
        "appVersion": "1",
        "language": "%(lang)s",
        "carrier": "carrier",
        "deviceModel": "deviceModel",
        "cmdDict": {
            "tts_voice": "Serena",
            "tts_language": "%(lang)s",
            "locale": "canada",
            "application_name": "Testing Python Script",
            "organization_id": "NUANCE",
            "phone_OS": "4.0",
            "phone_network": "wifi",
            "audio_source": "SpeakerAndMicrophone",
            "location": "%(location)s",
            "application_session_id": "1234567890",
            "utterance_number": "5",
            "ui_langugage": "en",
            "phone_submodel": "nmPhone2,1",
            "application_state_id": "45"        
        }
    }""" % (parameters)

    TEXT_TO_READ = """{
        "tts_type": "text"
    }"""

    TEXT_TO_READ = json.loads(TEXT_TO_READ)
    TEXT_TO_READ["tts_input"] = required_text
    TEXT_TO_READ = json.dumps(TEXT_TO_READ)

    request = Request()
    request.add_json_parameter("RequestData", None, RequestData)
    request.add_json_parameter("TtsParameter", "TEXT_TO_READ", TEXT_TO_READ)

    #ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    body, boundary = request.encode()
    h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
    #h.set_debuglevel(1)

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=%s" % (boundary,),
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    }

    h.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
    res = h.getresponse()

    data = """MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
""" + res.read()

    msg = email.message_from_string(data)

    for part in msg.walk():
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        payload = part.get_payload()

        if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
            ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename + '_ref', LNG)
            if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
                with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                    f_pcm.write(payload)

            cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename, LNG)
            with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                f_pcm.write(payload)

            compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)

        elif content_type == "application/json":
            with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, LNG), 'w') as f_json:
                f_json.write(payload)


filename = r'input.txt'

with open(filename) as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        LNG, text = line.strip().split('|')
        print "Getting {}: {}".format(LNG, text)
        get_tts(text, LNG)
```

This assumes your `input.txt` file has the following format:

```
ENG|I am tired
GED|Ich gehe nach hause
```

This will produce an output pcm and json file per line of text. It works with multiple files/languages.

Comment: it is generating plain1.txt. it is reading complete .txt file what is the res.read but it din parse it. can you help me ?

Comment: To help further (and be able to run the script) I would need to know the parameters needed to call `h.request`. The data you copy pasted in the question is not suitable.

Comment: can you please see once ?

Comment: I have added a simple way to extract the raw pcm to a file, I was able to hear the returned words.

Comment: thanks but how to read the remaining text in the res and write it to a another file ?

Comment: The returned data needed a suitable header to be added for the decoding to work correctly. It should work now.

Comment: That is all of the json payload, the remaining "text" in the response is just [MIME headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) and formatting, `print res.getheaders()` would show you this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102563/discussion-between-sam-and-martin-evans).

Comment: there will be several messages within input.txt. Finally I should have a respective .txt and .pcm for it.

Comment: million thanksss. how to save it as a .json instead of .txt ? so that I will have my code in json format

Comment: I did that but finally it does not contain data in json format. it will be in the form of .txt (horizontal line)

Comment: json can be horizontal or vertical, both will parse fine.

Comment: If I want to represent that in vertical . is it possible ?

Comment: I suggest you pass the language as a parameter to the function. See my edit.

Comment: but if it is ENG then go to that folder and if it is GED go to that path. how to do something like that ? request data varies from one language to another language. how can i do that ?

Comment: Just add another parameter to get_filename to specify the sub-folder

Comment: in my input.txt- one example is - ENG | I am tired. I will get the language as ENG (english). when I call get_tts. if LNG is ENG then take the specific request data and for other language then other request data. if I make the request data separate in the .json file, should I add TEXT_TO_READ also ? . how to read that as the input and send it as a request ?

Comment: You need to make changes to the JSON text. This could be done using a dictionary to substitute the 3 pieces of information. I have updated the solution.

Comment: thanks. but I have only one input.txt- which contains input as - ENG | I am tired and next- GED | Ich gehe nach hause and so on. What to do in such case ?

Comment: The line `file_inputs = [("GED", ".\.\DATA\GED\GED.txt"), ("ENG", ".\.\DATA\ENG\ENG.txt")]` lets you specify which files you want to parse, and select which language each is in.

Comment: thanks. I understood that but in my case there is only one input i.e input.txt - which contains - ENG | I am tired. next line  GED | Ich gehe nach hause and so on.

Comment: You mean you have changed your input file format to specify the language on each line? How do you delimit it? With a `|`?

Comment: the above code is throwing an error as   File ".\checking.py", line 172, in <module>
    for LNG, filename in file_inputs:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: It means you did not pass either ENG or GED as a language.

Comment: if I want to adopt this with a multiple server. how to do that ? give me some ideas, i will try myself.

Comment: It is very unlikely this would work with a different server as they will have completely different interfaces. It is also quite advanced to work out the correct request/response decoding. I suggest you pick a new server, find out if anyone has attempted something similar, write some code and post a new question.

Comment: I have same http request to the other servers also.

Comment: You could pass `host` as another parameter to `get_tts()`

Comment: if host , port and uri - all the three changes then how to adopt this code ?

Comment: how did you specify the boundary ? -  data = """MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--Nuance_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq
""" + res.read()  ..... In the above code- If i print res. it is printing in binary .

Comment: I printed the response and copied it.

Comment: I messaged you in chat. please reply there.

Comment: Sorry not near a computer this week. If you print data you should see the boundaries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587230/how-to-process-the-response-from-the-server-using-python

Answer (score -1):

Following sample should work for you.

```
filecontent = []
with open("Output.txt", "rb") as inputfile:
    for linenr, line in enumerate(inputfile):
        filecontent.append(line)
    linecount = linenr + 1

with open("AsciiOut.txt", "wb") as outputfile, open("BinOut.pcm", "wb") as binoutputfile:
    for linenr, line in enumerate(filecontent):
        if linenr < 4:
            outputfile.write(line)
        elif linenr < linecount - 12:
            binoutputfile.write(line)
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
```

Comment: You are solving the symptoms instead of the actual problem; what he really wants is to extract the various parts of a multipart mime message. The "row count" approach is bound to break at any minimum perturbation (including just changing the attached file to something which happens to have a newline in itself).