# How to process the response from the server using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
----G3wq

Com-data; name="Audio"; paramName="TEXT_TO_READ"

Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000

NContext: 6d46462d-f312-4352-bf01-0a220ed75ae4



ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿþÿþÿþÿþÿýÿþÿþÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ





    ÿÿÿÿýÿþÿýÿýÿúÿøÿúÿúÿúÿûÿþÿýÿùÿûÿüÿþÿüÿùÿúÿõÿ÷ÿóÿñÿôÿñÿïÿòÿñÿîÿîÿôÿóÿ÷ÿ÷ÿóÿõÿòÿïÿíÿðÿïÿ    ÿÿûÿïÿçÿäÿïÿïÿøÿþÿýÿóÿïÿèÿèÿàÿäÿæÿâÿìÿñÿ÷ÿøÿõÿõÿñÿïÿïÿðÿìÿæÿôÿõÿøÿúÿûÿøÿìÿóÿòÿýÿüÿûÿþÿýÿÿÿ÷ÿøÿüÿøÿõÿìÿïÿòÿ÷ÿúÿûÿ  üÿ÷ÿûÿ÷ÿ    
ÿÿÿÿòÿïÿïÿòÿýÿÿÿøÿõÿôÿîÿüÿ

þÿþÿùÿ#ÿÿøÿ
% :÷îfï

----N_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Audio"; paramName="TEXT_TO_READ"

Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000

Ne-Context: 6d46462d-f312-4352-bf01-0a220ed75ae4



‚ìÔáqâì÷ø
ûC\}IûÚ÷ö-ûMüäùøüï/˜?/.·\ÕîV’Š+³ÍcÛ¶Rúÿüÿ
âÿ±ÿ-×ÿbÿÖþ”þÓþ0ÿÎþ¾þÿ¬ÿœB“CéÛéŠ}¼ã,ÿ–ÿŽÿ=ÿ±þÿÀÅÿWÿ)N”õ¡Ïkÿîþ4þÒþ÷üÀüIýŸý¸þ'þ½üÅÿH’Z)ùÚ€ÿïûøüœýQýûúŠøéú‡þ‹âÿÿ…8^Í0Æ &ýwû?û?þbýú±ù)ÿè?´~¹¶’îuÿRýJü¡üÿ<þ¼þnþˆèr¢ÇnØnTÿûý©ý;üGû\ûsûëþ–ã‚óþt^Lçñ(»ýlÿ\K§™ýÀü—ý¢ÿ›þz ä¦ÿrÿÖ?à´åÿV=ÅiYRýÇýÿœ ‹®½éþåÿ¿ÿy‘Æýóüý%ý¦ÿ_•4ORò›³&U(ÿ?þTþ‹ÿ-ýŠúZú•ü4ÿjÿ«ûCüñþ’õ äïø‚þþ¢ÿÖþšû2úRú<üýõü¾ý~ýJG­FÕy(&èÿlþVÿ?þ‹ýÅý¤ÿwº®ÿäý—ÿœÛvþÜüýAû5þLþ!þü»ù|ü†þÂþÀÀþÉÿ“ãÙu­úNíÕ,þËü#ýfýÄæÿJþxü¶ý‘~596Žn…w?ÜGý‰ýöüáþÇþÖý7ÿœýVÿsÿC€´
öýøüþ¢”·’þ*ýBþýÝû9ýøú2üŸü   úJû²ú
```

ù‰ÿ·“û#÷Wü ý2yýþþ‰ýýòÿkÙÂûVüæÁâÿûù§ùAøýKoÎÿ0þð'ü™üºù%üòü?
    ¼7MH.HýúÉª5YxqÿåÿñýIþÌ

```
FSÉþÛüõúdùü÷¿öMõèóšò?ñóð†ðsðAð5ðððòïÐï˜ïºïðjðÅðãð†ð
ð?ïï î'îî×í£íüììÎê?é€èÂççiæˆå¢äªãÔâÝáá>àäß-à±àá‰áwáCáŒá=â¥ãAå>ç éëÂìäî[ñô÷ú9ý¤›†7Ÿ? Ê¼d Œ#K&Y(*?+ù,%.Þ.Q/î/,00ˆ/§.«-$,ª*E)È'!&H$?"ï5+gHë|$¼>    ˜F
Ãÿ‹ýëûuúúøn÷øõÊôxóRò^ñ€ðöï^ïòî{îÇííwìþë›ëAëÝêªêQêþéŠéîèQèœçÞæ[æøåeåå{äïãã=â?ááóàá&á'áôà­à¸àá¬áµâÄãÚäæ,çeè¶é³ëêí„ðÓòõõ÷¿úçýoY;“»àÑO"Ý$R'§)–+z-Í.û/‡0Ý0!1J11s0‡/6.Ú,h+*?(ù%q#î y
kØ L©.} åCÐÿ³ý¯ûáùø{öÒôBóîñ…ð¢ïåî0î‚íÂì.ì²ëBëâêtêê›é9éçè¦èMèèÈçwç×æFæäå˜åmåRå4åÚäZäöã?ãdã=ãWã¥ãäsäÈäå åfå;æ…çöèIêµë@íˆîðËñÞóþõ"øjú­ý`îéu
¡OÄ?ð÷„     "Ì#b%E&›'â(£)*-*ó)Ç)u)é(>(Â'?&J%Ë#á! íÁ‹%è¤wá)³2ìþþüûùïöõ9óQñ›ï=îíÀë©ê?é˜è¡ç¥æ¿ååqäääÙã¹ã?ãgãJããÖâÕâðâ1ã›ãýãKä9ääVäÀäJå+æSç@è¨è$éêIë£ìî›ïLñ
óõ<÷)ùúHü?þÿÍ–  %ýgôm¦âlLÎ0 a!  "š"<#È#ü#M$%±%/%ë#Ð","»!ó  «9¸´Åô6\
0ê>eÿþ#ý›ü½ûŠúQùaøÌ÷0÷Šöíõ’õBõïôˆôôyó*ó?óióŒó?óÑóô[ô‘ô´ôõôYõñõ‡öòöL÷{÷º÷û÷ ø?øxøîø‰ù6úÅúûoûÐûAü¡üýbý¶ý#þwþÿcÿuÿsÿzÿºÿïÿ!8A9(ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

----NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="QueryResult"

Content-Type: application/JSON; charset=utf-8

N-Context: 6d46462d-f312-4352-bf01-0a220ed75ae4

{"TTSStatus":"Success","result_type":"NVC_TTS_CMD","NMAS_PRFX_SESSION_ID":"23de3ddd-62b9-407c-88f0-1f81d7c1e475","NMAS_PRFX_TRANSACTION_ID":"1"}

---NNMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq--
```

I was just getting a header, binary data and TTSStatus from the server but now I am getting as above nothing but getting header, binary, header, binary and TTSStatus. The below code is working fine when I was just getting a header, binary data and TTSStatus from the server.

Can someone please tell me how to modify it ?

```
for part in msg.walk():
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        payload = part.get_payload()
        try:
            #if there is no reference file exist then create one based on the response 

            if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
                ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename + '_ref', outputfolder)
                if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
                    with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                        f_pcm.write(payload)

                else:
                    print "[Warning] Reference PCM file is already there"

                cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename, outputfolder)
                if len(cur_filename):
                    with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                        f_pcm.write(payload)

                else:
                    print "[ERROR] Not able to create a Response PCM file \n"

                Error_Status = compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)

            #copy the header or the json response from the server

            elif content_type == "application/json":
                with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, outputfolder), 'w') as f_json:
                    f_json.write(payload)
        except:
            print "\n[ERROR] Can't Create Reference PCM or Response JSON files!"
            Error_Status = 1
```

Comment: Martin Evans- can you please tell me how ?

Comment: Has the boundary changed on the MIME data? Try building `data` as follows: `data = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: {}\n{}".format(res.getheader('content-type'), res.read())`

Comment: thanks. but it is not working.

Comment: Not sure what you have changed,  the old code still works for me.

Comment: Martin Evans : I can explain like this : before I was giving input like ENG|I am tired - this text is small in length so my code was working properly and getting output in one segment. now the input is like ENG|I am hungry, so I am going to restaurant. Hence I am getting in segments. First I will get I am hungry then remaining input will be processed. I think . I have to modify the code in if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload): can you please tell me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are sometimes getting two PCM blocks back for each request. Previously the second entry was empty.

The following will add a segment number to the end of each file. It is based on my original code, so you will need to apply the changes to your full current script:

```
    data = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: {}\n{}".format(res.getheader('content-type'), res.read())
    msg = email.message_from_string(data)
    segment = 1

    for part in msg.walk():
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        payload = part.get_payload()

        if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
            pcm_filename = '{}_{}'.format(output_filename, segment)
            segment += 1

            ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', pcm_filename + '_ref', LNG)
            if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
                with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                    f_pcm.write(payload)

            cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', pcm_filename, LNG)
            with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                f_pcm.write(payload)

            compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)

        elif content_type == "application/json":
            with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, LNG), 'w') as f_json:
                f_json.write(payload)
```

You could also change the following line:

```
output_filename = "".join([x if x.isalnum() else "_" for x in required_text[:80]]).replace('__', '_').strip('_')
```

This will have the effect of removing any double underscores or trailing underscores from your output file names.

---

Alternatively, if you want to append all of the segments together, you could try something like the following version. Unfortunately, I was not able to recreate the multi-segment response and so was not able to test this to see if it is possible to just append the various segments together and for it to still play correctly:

```
    data = "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: {}\n{}".format(res.getheader('content-type'), res.read())
    msg = email.message_from_string(data)
    wav_data = []

    for part in msg.walk():
        content_type = part.get_content_type()
        payload = part.get_payload()

        if content_type == "audio/x-wav" and len(payload):
            wav_data.append(payload)
        elif content_type == "application/json":
            with open(get_filename('json', output_filename, LNG), 'w') as f_json:
                f_json.write(payload)

    if len(wav_data):
        payload = ''.join(wav_data)

        ref_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename + '_ref', LNG)
        if not os.path.exists(ref_filename):
            with open(ref_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
                f_pcm.write(payload)

        cur_filename = get_filename('pcm', output_filename, LNG)
        with open(cur_filename, 'wb') as f_pcm:
            f_pcm.write(payload)

        compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename)
```